# How to write unit test to my volley API call in android

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, android-volley

This is my MainActivity, I am unable to understand and write the unit test code for this can someone help me by providing reference or the code for this problem.In the main activity I have created the methods to call the API how can I mock the API response and get the unit tests for this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String TAG = "MainActivity";
private final String Url="https://dev-smartoffice-api.sharpb2bcloud.com/rmi/v1/checkVersion";
IResult mResultCallback = null;
public MainActivity(IResult iResult)
{
    this.mResultCallback=iResult;
}
VolleyService mVolleyService;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initVolleyCallback();
    mVolleyService.getDataVolley("GETCALL",Url);
    mVolleyService = new VolleyService(mResultCallback,this);
    JSONObject sendObj = null;

    try {
        sendObj = new JSONObject("{'Test':'Test'}");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 //   mVolleyService.postDataVolley("POSTCALL", "http://localhost/androidphpmysql/registrationapi.php?apicall=login", sendObj);
}
void initVolleyCallback(){

        mResultCallback = new IResult() {
        @Override
        public void notifySuccess(String request,JSONObject response) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


            @Override
        public void notifyError(String requestType, VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           // return error;
        }
    };
}
```

}

These are my interfaces,here there are two interfaces notify-success and notify error with return type void I don't know how to use them for mocking please help me

```
public interface IResult {
public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONObject response);
public void notifyError(String requestType, VolleyError error);
```

}

This is my volleyservice class

```
public class VolleyService {

    IResult mResultCallback = null;
    Context mContext;
JSONObject message;

    public VolleyService(IResult resultCallback, Context context){
        mResultCallback = resultCallback;
        mContext = context;
    }


    public void postDataVolley(final String requestType, String url,JSONObject sendObj){
        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObj = new JsonObjectRequest(url,sendObj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    if(mResultCallback != null)
                        mResultCallback.notifySuccess(requestType,response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if(mResultCallback != null)
                        mResultCallback.notifyError(requestType,error);
                }
            })
            {
                @Override
                public Map getHeaders() throws Error {
                HashMap headers = new HashMap();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                headers.put("client-type","SYNAPPX");
                headers.put("client-version","1.1.0");
                headers.put("operating-system", "ANDROID");
                headers.put("os-version", "8.0");
                return headers;
            }
            };

            queue.add(jsonObj);

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }

    public void getDataVolley(final String requestType, String url){

        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObj = new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.GET,url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    if(mResultCallback != null)
                        mResultCallback.notifySuccess(requestType,response);
                    message=response;
                }
            },new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if(mResultCallback != null)
                        mResultCallback.notifyError(requestType, error);
                }
            }){
                @Override
                public Map getHeaders() throws Error {
                    HashMap headers = new HashMap();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    headers.put("client-type","SYNAPPX");
                    headers.put("client-version","1.1.0");
                    headers.put("operating-system", "ANDROID");
                    headers.put("os-version", "8.0");
                    return headers;
                }
            };

            queue.add(jsonObj);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: the basic idea is to avoid creating the dependency directly in the class that needs it, but use, e.g., dependency injection instead

Comment: @njzk2 can i get an sample code

Comment: Try this. https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection